# Обучение CSharp и unity и полный тупизм

Tags: c#, unity3d-android

Переход между сценами.

> Scene 'Game' couldn't be loaded because it has not been added to the
>   build settings or the AssetBundle has not been loaded. To add a scene
>   to the build settings use the menu File->Build Settings...
>   UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager:LoadScene(String)
>   ButtonsMenu:PlayPressed() (at Assets/Scripts/ButtonsMenu.cs:10)
>   UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class ButtonsMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void PlayPressed()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Game");
    }
}
```

Comment: Извините, а каков же ваш вопрос?

Comment: Думаю, ежели сразу видна ошибка и скрин - значит это проблема в коде)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в окне(на картинке) в меню Build settings сцена "game2",а в скрипте "Game".Либо поменяйте название сцены,либо в скрипте исправьте название сцены на "game2" (именно с маленькой буквы)

Upd: и поменяйте сцены местами(это имеет значение),просто перетащив вниз сцену "game2"(как файлы в папке)